# NSDictionary to NSData and NSData to NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsdata

I am not sure if I am using the dictionary or the data object or both incorrectly. I m trying to get used to the switch to swift but I'm having a little trouble.

```
var dictionaryExample : [String:AnyObject] =
    ["user":"UserName",
     "pass":"password",
    "token":"0123456789",
    "image":0] // image should be either NSData or empty

let dataExample : NSData = dictionaryExample as NSData
```

I need the `NSDictionary` to encode to an `NSData` object as well as taking that `NSData` object and decode it into a `NSDictionary`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Saying "convert NSDictionary to NSData" is meaningless if you don't specify a format for the NSData.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`

Example for swift 2.0+

```
var dictionaryExample : [String:AnyObject] = ["user":"UserName", "pass":"password", "token":"0123456789", "image":0]
let dataExample : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionaryExample)
let dictionary:NSDictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataExample)! as? NSDictionary
```

**Swift3.0**

```
let dataExample: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionaryExample)
let dictionary: Dictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dataExample) as! [String : Any]
```

Screenshot of playground

[image]

Comment: You did answer my question specifed in the title. I think AnyObject was wrong. I want to have the user/pass/token be strings and the image be an nsdata object. Am I able to do that? or should i encode them all into NSData objects and then decode them afterwards?

Comment: class func unarchiveObjectWithData(data: NSData) -> AnyObject? This is from the doc of xocde.

Comment: Nevermind when i end up using them i just say data.valueForKey("user") as string

Thanks for the help this thread can now close

Comment: This doesn't work. This produces error `'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary';`

Comment: @c.dunlap I have update the code. I answered the answer when it is swift 1.2. So,for swift 2.0,it may have some syntax issue

Comment: This does not work because the function unarchiveObject(with:) takes a variable of type Data, whereas the function unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData() takes a variable of type NSData. See my answer

Answer (score 11):

***Swift 5***

as @yuyeqingshan said, `PropertyListSerialization` is a good option

```
       // Swift Dictionary To Data.
        do {
            let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: [:], format: PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.binary, options: 0)
            // do sth
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }


        // Data to Swift Dictionary
        do {
            let dicFromData = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions.mutableContainers, format: nil)
            if let dict = dicFromData as? [String: Any]{
                // do sth
            }
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

NSPropertyListSerialization may be an alternative solution.

```
// Swift Dictionary To Data.
var data = try NSPropertyListSerialization.dataWithPropertyList(dictionaryExample, format: NSPropertyListFormat.BinaryFormat_v1_0, options: 0)

// Data to Swift Dictionary
var dicFromData = (try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: NSPropertyListReadOptions.Immutable, format: nil)) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3:

```
let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: authResponse, format: PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.binary, options: 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376608/2901306) gave me build time errors because `NSData` isn't the same as `Data`. The function `unarchiveObject(with:)` takes a variable of type `Data`, whereas the function `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData()` takes a variable of type `NSData`.

This is a working **Swift 3** answer:

```
var names : NSDictionary = ["name":["John Smith"], "age": 35]
let namesData : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: names) as NSData
do{
    let backToNames = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(namesData) as! NSDictionary
    print(backToNames)
}catch{
    print("Unable to successfully convert NSData to NSDictionary")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For Swift 4 -

```
let dictionaryExample : [String:AnyObject] = ["user":"UserName" as AnyObject, "pass":"password" as AnyObject, "token":"0123456789" as AnyObject, "image":0 as AnyObject]
    let dataExample : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionaryExample) as NSData
    let dictionary:NSDictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dataExample as Data)! as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: Bad example. You say "Swift 4" but you're casting NSData to Data instead of using Data directly, you're using AnyObject instead of Any, and your usage of optionals is far from optimal...