# Convert Dictionary<String: Any?> to NSData

Tags: swift, xcode7, eureka-forms

I am using the swift form class Eureka to to build my form. On button submit I get my fields using form.values(). This gives me the following

```
let formvalues = form.values()
```

print(formvalues)

```
["field1":Optional(20), "field2": Optional("")]
```

I am trying to post the field names/values

Comment: Are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376469/nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-nsdata-to-nsdictionary-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way to serialize a dictionary containing `Any` type values in it. `Any` can be any swift construct, including objects, structs, tuples, etc. There is no one-size-fits-all serialization that supports serializing any data type like that.

Now if you have a dictionary of type `<String: String>, <String: Int>`, or other fixed types, then you could use `NSJSONSerialization` to export it as JSON. You just need to stick to the types defined by JSON. You could also export it as XML or a plist file.