# Converting Data to JSON String using Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `NSData` object which needs to be converted to `[String:Any]` and here is the code I tried:

```
let multiOrder = _fields["multiOrder"] as? GPBValue
if let _ = multiOrder {
  let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: multiOrder!)
  if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(responseString)
  }
}
```

`GPBValue` object  looks like `NSObject<NSSecureCoding, NSCopying>`

But the above code is returning `nil`

Comment: Use: `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDictionary to NSData and NSData to NSDictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376469/nsdictionary-to-nsdata-and-nsdata-to-nsdictionary-in-swift)